# WPF Command-Canexecute-Revalidation

Tags: c#, wpf, command

I've just written a little game using wpf. There is a matrix of cells I can click. The click events are working through a DelegateCommand. The problem is that the canexecute method is not called. I always have to click somewhere on the window first. 
I never had problems with my commandclass because I was using this:

```
event EventHandler ICommand.CanExecuteChanged
{
    add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
    remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
}
```

I also tried to call CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested(); but that also does not work. 
The Cells are clickable if the currentuser that is allowed to click it, is the local user of my pc(it is multiplayer). So I called InvalidateRequerySuggested after I get the Message from the network that I  am the "currentplayer" now.

```
private void SetTurn(TurnMessage message)
{
    CurrentPlayer = GetPlayer(message.PlayerID);
    System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
}
```

That will have this affect:

```
    public bool HasTurn
    {
        get { return CurrentPlayer != null && CurrentPlayer.PlayerID == Player.PlayerID; }
    }
```

My Command Can-Execute looks like this:

```
private bool CanMatrixClick(Object param)
{
    return Main.PlayerViewModel.HasTurn;
}
```

So has anyone a clean and easy solution for this problem?
I really could not find anything which I had not tried already.

Answer (score 0):

`DelegateCommand` have method [`RaiseCanExecuteChanged()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.prism.commands.delegatecommandbase.raisecanexecutechanged%28v=pandp.39%29.aspx) which you can call manually to fire the `CanExecute` Event -

```
private void SetTurn(TurnMessage message)
{
    CurrentPlayer = GetPlayer(message.PlayerID);
    YourCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
}
```

Comment: I've also tried this. I really don't know why. I've written big projects using mvvm and this classes without any problems.

Comment: I found the problem but I have no solution: There is no Eventhandler for the CanExecuteChanged-Event on the command. And there is also no result if I call InvalidateRequerySuggested(). But I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

Only for others, who get maybe into this problem: Be carefull where you call `InvalidateRequerySuggested`. You have to call it in the UI-Thread.

For me the dispatcher solved the problem

```
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke ((Action) (() =>
                {
                    CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
                }));
```